# Modify elements in a list by index

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I need to modify a `List<int>`  by indexes. I have the indexes in another `List<int>`

```
List<int> values;
List<int> indexes;

indexes.Select(i=>values[i]).ForEach(val=>val = 0);
```

Of course, I know the above syntax wont work. However, as I know the indexes of the items that I need to modify, I would like to to modify the list with the indexes with lambda. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some cases, LINQ isn't going to give you a particularly better solution, especially when working with indices or when modifying data. I think the following simple `foreach` loop will be probably the most readable way to write this:

```
foreach(var i in indexes) values[i] = 0;
```

However, if the collection `indexes` is of type `List<T>` then you can use the `ForEach` method (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx)). This makes the code a little shorter, but it is a question whether it is more readable than simple `foreach` loop:

```
indexes.ForEach(i => values[i] = 0);
```

`ForEach` method is not currently available in LINQ (for general `IEnumerable<T>`), but there are quite a few people asking for it. But as I said, it is not clear whether it makes code more readable or not.

(If you wanted to write the same thing for `IEnumerable<T>` you'd have to either use `ToList` or write your own `ForEach` extension method).

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but is this all you are looking for?

```
foreach(int index in indexes)
{
    values[index] = 0; // your modified value here
}
```

Comment: sorry to confuse you. What I meant to ask is there a lambda expression to do that? I will edit my post

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use LINQ. You could do something as simple as this. It also keeps the meaning clearer, I think.

```
foreach(int index in indexes)
{
    values[index] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course, but what I meant to ask is the lambda. Sorry for that.Edited the post.